# How to add element to array without rewriting previous? - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to add elements to an array after typing their name, but for some reason when I do

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $u = array("billy\n", "tyson\n", "sanders\n");
    serialize($u);
    file_put_contents('pass.txt', $u);

    if (isset($_POST['set'])) {
        unserialize($u);
        array_push($u, $_POST['check']);
        file_put_contents('pass.txt', $u);
    }
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="check"/><br>
    <input type="submit" name="set" value="Add person"/><br>
    <?php echo print_r($u); ?>
</form>
```

It puts it in the array, but when I do it again, it rewrites the previous written element. Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean after typing their name?

Comment: I was referring to my entire script, it's about typing your name, and it being added to the array and so on, I just didn't want to show it all.

Comment: Then show an example where this issue can be reproduced. It [works fine](https://eval.in/142247) for me.

Comment: @user3504199 can you show the form etc?

Comment: You can't keep arrays from different form submits, to do that you will need to use $_SESSION['person'][] = $u;

Comment: @user3504199: `file_put_contents()` overwrite the file contents by default. You need to use `FILE_APPEND` flag to **append** data. Change the second `file_put_contents()` to: `file_put_contents('pass.txt', $u, FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: @AmalMurali I'm trying to keep the array from overwriting it's previous written element. Not keep the file from overwriting itself.

Comment: @MISJHA Didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always start with the same array, which means no matter what you do you're going to only be able to add one person. I /think/ you're trying to add each person to the file, which can be accomplished by modifying the code to resemble something like this:

```
session_start();

$contents = file_get_contents('pass.txt');    

if (isset($_POST['set'])) {
    $u = unserialize($contents);
    array_push($u, $_POST['check'] . "\n");
    $u = serialize($u);
    file_put_contents('pass.txt', $u);
}
```

Notice also that you can't use `[un]serialize()` on its own, it must be used in the setting of a variable.

**Note: Personally, I'd just go the easy route and do `$u[] = $_POST['check']`, as using `array_push()` to push one element seems a bit... overkill.

Comment: But what if I wanted to add an element to the array aswell?